# Using jQuery effects on appended HTML

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

I have my code here.

```
// HTML Code
<div class="article"></div>

// jQuery
$('.article').append('<a href="" class="toggle">Toggle div</a>');
```

Is it possible to use that newly created href link and toggle a div like this:

```
// jQuery
$('.toggle').click(function() { 
   $('.article').toggle('slow');
});
```

I have tried the above with no luck. I just get redirected to index page.

Comment: Post some more code in a jsfiddle? So we can have some context of how you are using your code.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/HgG9U/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `click()`: it's deprecated and wouldn't work even if it weren't. Use [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
$('.toggle').on('click', function() { 
   $('.article').toggle('slow');
});
```

Also, change your `a` tag to `<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="toggle">Toggle div</a>`.

---

As to the reason why `on()` works and `click()` doesn't, you need to read jQuery's documentation. In short, the click event has been bound to an element on the page; this scope does not cover future elements that are added to the DOM. `On()`, however, is a delegated event:

> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from
>   descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By
>   picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the
>   delegated event handler is attached, you can use delegated events to
>   avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers.

Comment: It'd be good to explain why this is the case (beyond the deprecation).

Comment: Thanks for the advice about the click, but the appended html still only takes me back to the index page instead of toggle the '.article' class

Comment: Put `javascript:void(0)` in your `href=""` attribute. See updated answer.

Comment: You can also `return false;` at the end of your click event handler.